# Two functions that have the same Fourier coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, ergodic-theory

We define a function $T:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,1)$ s.t $T(x)=2x$ if $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $T(x)=2x-1$ if $x\in [\frac{1}{2},1)$. $T$ obviously has a period of $\frac{1}{2}$. Now we look at $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ 1-periodic and integrable function, and we want to find the relation between its Fourier coefficients and the Fourier coefficients of $f\circ T$.

My go was: $2\hat f\circ T(k)=2\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0f(2x)e^{-4\pi ikx}dx+2\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0f(2x-1)e^{-4\pi ikx}dx$. By change of variables $u=2x,t=2x-1$, I then get:

$$2\hat f\circ T(k)=\int^{1}_0f(u)e^{-2\pi iku}du+\int^{1}_0f(t)e^{-2\pi ik(t+1)}dt=\hat f(k)+e^{-2\pi it}\hat f(k)=2\hat f(k).$$

Is it possible for two different functions to have the same Fourier coefficients? (The goal is to prove that such $T$ is ergodic).

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569948/uniqueness-of-fourier-transform-in-l1) might help.

Comment: Two (integrable) functions with the same Fourier coefficients are identical ae;

Comment: what you get is if $g=f \circ T$ then $\hat g(2k)=\hat f(k)$ as the first integral is not $\hat g(k)$ since it has $e^{-4\pi ikx}$ not $e^{-2\pi i kx}$ as integrand; note that $(\hat f) \circ T$ makes no sense as they have different domains

Comment: @Conrad I wasn't able to put the hat over the whole function. Why is it equal to $\hat g(2k)$? we were taught that the integrand is dependent on the length of the period. Since it's period is $\frac{1}{2}$, I get that the integrand is supposed to be $e^{-4\pi ikx}$, or am I wrong?

Comment: $f$ has period $1$ so in order to talk about functions have same Fourier coefficients, we ned to take them on same interval; it is true that you can restrict $g$ to half the unit interval and do a Fourier series there but then the integral is only the first part $\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0f(2x)e^{-4\pi ikx}dx$ by the definition of the Fourier series (in other words you integrate the appropriate exponential on the period which here would be only $[0,1/2]$) and then you have two different functions, two different Fourier expansions (one $\sum a_ne^{2\pi i nx}$, the other $\sum a_ne^{4\pi i nx}$)

Comment: in other words, if you give me a sequence of numbers say absolutely convergent, $a_n, n \in \mathbb Z, \sum |a_n| < \infty$, in order to define a Fourier series and a periodic function (which is continuous here by absolute convergence), you need to specify the period; of course, such functions will be related by a linear change of variables $x \to cx+d$, as it is the case for $f$ on $[0,1]$ and $f \circ T$ restricted to $[0, 1/2]$ by the definition of $T$

Comment: @Conrad So how should I treat this problem, as T doesn't behave the same over the interval $[0,1)$? Especially if I want to find the relation between $\hat f(k)$ and the fourier coefficients of $f\circ T$?

Comment: I can't delete this comment.