# Interpreting the function when the given Improper integral is zero

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

[image]

What are the things I can say about this function g?I feel it has got something to do with Fourier transform,but the only thing I can see is g is zero.

I am looking at other sorts of interpretations.

Can I have an inner product here?

The equation holds good for all possible values of k.

Comment: Yes, this is (one variant of) the Fourier transform of $g$. Are you assuming that the equation holds for all $k \in \mathbb R$, or for one particular $k$?

Comment: @Bungo I edited

Comment: Your question is essentially the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/569948/169852). The answer (assuming this is a Lebesgue integral and $g \in L^1$) is that you can conclude that $g = 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes this part is clear to me,but are there any other interpretations?Can I have an inner product here?

Comment: Sure, you could interpret the integral as an inner product, as long as you're careful about what space the inner product applies to. $e^{ikx}$ is not in $L^1$.

Comment: I don't know about L¹ space,can you say more about it?Also why does e^ikx not belong to L¹?

Comment: Can I define it as a sum of infinite series?